# WordPress Parent and Child item links do not work SEO on Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, nginx, seo

I am using the latest WordPress build on Ubuntu on NGINX.

My NGINX configuration for WordPress is setup like:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
```

If I create a page called `About` and have slug (URL) like `/about/` and then I create another page called `History` and have it as a child of the About (this being the parent)

The slug becomes

`/about/history`

However, when I try to access the page, it spits 404.

`/about` works as normal. This 404 triggers with trailing slash and without. Can I not make content like

```
/main

/main/sub

/main/sub/sub
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed this:

```
# location / {
#         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
#}
```

Replaced with:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```